# Tooltip for QPushButton 

Tags: qt, text, button, comments, rollover

Is there a possibility to add a tooltip to a QPushButton. I mean, that when you roll over the button a small textbox appears (usually yellow) and tells users what this button is doing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`QPushButton` is a [`QWidget`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#toolTip-prop), so it has the `setToolTip(const QString&)` like all other widgets.

Either that's what you're looking for, or you're after the `setWhatsThis(const QString&)` function. More info in the [`QWhatsThis`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QWhatsThis.html) documentation.

Comment: I just came across this and noticed that the links are broken. Take [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#toolTip-prop) and [that](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QWhatsThis.html)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Theolodis, fixed!